# Postgres: authenticate as postgres user in non-interactive script

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a non-interactive script that needs to execute postgres commands.  The script will only be run by `root` or a user with `sudo` permissions, and the postgres commands need to be executed as the `postgres` user in postgresql.  The trouble is that postgresql always (as far as I can tell) prompts for a password interactively (i.e. `pqsl -U postgres -W`) or does not accept a password at all (i.e. `psql -U postgres -w`).  I would like to pass a password on the command line, similar to how mysql allows `mysql -u user -p password`.  How can I do this with postgres?

Comment: What language are you using? Shell?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. `-p password` leaves your password visible in, for example, `ps xa` output.

Comment: I'm using a bash script.  And @derobert, so if I shouldn't do it this way, then how do I run postgres commands non-interactively *at all*? I'm going to need to authenticate to the postgres server somehow.

Comment: @jayhendren you can set up your pg_hba.conf file to use `peer` or `ident` authentication (if the script is running on the same machine as postgres) or you can use a `~/.pgpass` file.

Comment: It will ask for passwords even if you execute your script as postgres using `crontab`? I have some scripts running directly as `postgres` scheduled, and it works out of the box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing the same thing .

**Approach 1 :**

Add a `.pgpass` file in home directory of user(user which runs the script):

```
$ cat /home/user/.pgpass
hostname:port:database:user:password
$ chmod 600 /home/user/.pgpass
```

After adding the above you don't need to add password in any script you using. It will connect directly.

**Approach 2 :**

Add the following in your shell script. But this will expose your password and become a problem if you are committing to any repository.

```
export PGPASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable. For instance:

```
PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -U postgres -c "<postgresql query>"
```

[Source](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpass)

Comment: Not the mosy secure solution, as the process environment can be sniffed. See .pgpass solution or modify postgres_hba.conf

Answer (score 1):

If you can run psql as the user postgres, the most useful solution is to modify pg_hba.conf so the the Unix user postgres, connecting via localhost/socket, is authenticated without any password pr external file. At the tip of the file, insert this:

```
local all postgres  peer
```

This, TBMI is the default. Perhaps someone thought they were being clever or more secure when they removed this line, idk. You could also use something like this for a monitroing service:

```
local zabbix zabbix peer
```

for which you create a username&database named "zabbix".